# Changing part of a line in a text file in bash

Tags: bash, variables, sed, text-files, field

I have a line in a text file, for example:

> abcde:jhdfj$jhbsfiy/.hghi$jh:12345:dgve::

and I want to replace the 3rd field, 12345, with a variable. Without touching the rest of it and without copying anything to a variable... help? Yes, it's a uni question essentially :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
v="new val"
echo "abcde:jhdfj$jhbsfiy/.hghi$jh:12345:dgve::" | awk -F: -v new=${v} 'OFS=FS; $3=new'
```

Comment: OK, how do i also get it only to apply to a line in a text file with the line where the 1st field starts with var1

Comment: I got it working in sed but not with special characters in the second field

Comment: If you have a completely new question, it is better to explain it properly in starting from scratch on "ask question". Here in comments it is difficult to print code and look for a solution.

Comment: OK. can i remove the echo part and start from the awk?

Comment: You need to give `awk` the string to work with. If you have it in a file you can directly `awk <some things> file`

Comment: By the way, if @Imagination or my answer solved your problem, you can mark your question as answered.

Answer (score 0):

this line should work for your requirement:

```
awk -F: '{$3="55555"}1' OFS=":" file
```

the `55555` is the new string.

Comment: what if i want to change field 2 and 4 to 7 but leave 1 and 3 alone?

Comment: the new string is also a variable

Comment: @StevenCragg in awk, `$1` is the first column, `$100` is the 100th column. just change the columns you want by this pattern. if the new values follow some pattern or rules. you could do it in a loop. `awk -v n="$newVar" '{$3=n}1' OFS=":" file` will work for variable.

Comment: Thanks. And to apply it to a line starting with a variable? for example var1 = abcde

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -i "s/:[0-9]*:/:$VAR:/1" INPUTFILE
```

where $VAR contains what you're wanting to replace the third field with.

or

```
sed -i "s/:[0-9]*:/:NewText:/1" INPUTFILE
```

where NewText is the amount you want to replace.

If you would rather just do it on a stdin then you could

```
echo "stdin Teststring" | sed -i "s/:[0-9]*:/:$VAR:/1"
```